# How to print using iframe? ID does not get when print button is click

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, printing

I want to print information that depends on the $stud_no using iframe. When I show the iframe in the table, it generates a correct $stud_no. But when I click the print button it only shows the First $stud_no. It's like the button didn't GET the id in **admin_print-app-form-view.php**

> **admin_print-app-form.php**

```php
<table id="dataTable2" class="text-center">
    <thead class="text-capitalize">
        <tr>
            <th>NO.</th>
            <th>LAST NAME</th>
            <th>FIRST NAME</th>
            <th>MIDDLE NAME</th>
            <th>SEX</th>
            <th>CONTACT NO.</th>
            <th>ENTRY</th>
            <th>ACTION</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM stud_acc";
            $result = $con->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $iframeId = 'studframe' . $row['stud_no'];
                $stud_no = $row['stud_no'];
                $lastname = $row['lastname'];
                $firstname = $row['firstname'];
                $middlename = $row['middlename'];
                $sex = $row['sex'];
                $contact = $row['contact'];
                $entry = $row['entry'];?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $stud_no ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $lastname ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $firstname ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $middlename ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $sex ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contact ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry ?></td>
            <td>
                <iframe src="admin_print-app-form-view.php?id=<?php echo "$stud_no"?>" name="frame" id="<?= $iframeId ?>" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px"></iframe>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-roundedtb btn-info" onclick="document.getElementById('<?= $iframeId ?>').print();"><i class="fa fa-print"></i><span class="icon-name"> Print</span></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        } }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

> **admin_print-app-form-view.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("connection.php");
    $stud_no = $_GET['id'];
?>
```

This is the print preview.The number in the Red circle should be the $stud_no that I clicked, but it always gives me first stud_no
[image: The number in the Red circle should be the $stud_no]

Comment: This code will give all generated iframes the same name and id. Id's _must_ be unique within a document. Then you can use the ID to locate the iframe you want to print. Right now, it seems like it's printing the same iframe no matter what button you cllick. There's no magic in the browser that assumes/guesses what iframe your'e actually trying to target. You must explicitly target the specific iframe.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes you're right. I keep getting the same iframe. But when the visibility of the iframe in the table is not hidden, it shows the correct stud_no. Why is it like that?

Comment: You're creating multiple iframes and you are passing the correct values. The problem is only that your JS `frames['frame']` always refers to the same iframe, which means that you're printing the same iframe on every button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you give the same name and id to every iframe, javascript will only give you the first match it finds, returning the same iframe for all buttons.

We need to give them unique id's (we can skip the name altogether).

*Note: This code assumes that `stud_no` is a unique value, like the tables primary key.*

In your `while`-loop, create a unique id:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Create a unique id using the stud_no
    $iframeId = 'studframe' . $row['stud_no'];
```

Now give the iframe that id:

```
<iframe ... id="<?= $iframeId ?>" ... ></iframe>
```

And make sure the button refers to that id:

```
<button ... onclick="document.title=''; document.getElementById('<?= $iframeId ?>').print();">...</button>
```

In the above code, I've created unique id's by prefixing them with `studframe` and then added the `stud_no` so it becomes `id="studframe1"`, `id="studframe2"` and so on.

Then when referring to that specific iframe, we're fetching the iframe based on that unique id.

Comment: Nothing happens now when i clicked the button :'( I tried using your idea in name instead of id but it also didn't work.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the attempt? I would need to se your implementation. (Don't change the current question, just add the new code as an edit).

Comment: Hello sir! It works now. This is what I did. 
 
`<iframe src="admin_print-app-form-view.php?id=<?php echo "$stud_no"?>" name="<?php echo $iframeId; ?>" id="iframeid" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px"></iframe>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-roundedtb btn-info" onclick="document.title='';frames['<?php echo $iframeId; ?>'].print();"><i class="fa fa-print"></i><span class="icon-name"> Print</span></button> `

Thank you for your idea. Really appreciated it :)

Comment: @bwi - Either set the id to use the variable as well or remove the id attribute completely. As mentioned, id's _must_ be unique within the document. Having the same id for multiple elements is invalid.

Comment: Okay sir. Noted. Thank you very much for your help ☺️